# wishy-washy caffè frappè

Tags: coffee, drinks

I'm trying to do the Greek drink "Caffè Frappè". I'm using 2 tea spoon of spray dried coffee and 2 tea spoons of sugar. I've added a little of iced water and blended with an hand mixer until it's whipped. After that I add water until the glass is full, but the water/coffee is too much diluted. Am I making any mistake? Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also recommend that you find dried coffee by Nescafe - specifically the Greek brand if you can find it.  Depending on where you live it can be hard to find but is totally worth it and for some reason foams better than regular Nescafe.  If you search the internetz you will find that there is a Nescafe with a label written in Greek.  This is the one you want!

Once you have strong enough dried coffee to start with then it is only a matter of ratios with water and the coffee.  Experiment, but two teaspoons sounds like not enough - I'd start with a tablespoon to 3 tablespoons water.  Pour over ice.  Add water after you have mixed it but be careful not to ruin the foam you just created.  Remember the ice will start to melt immediately also making your frappe taste wishy washy so make it stronger from the start.

Comment: The Nescafé they use in Greece is called "Nescafé Classic". In Switzerland where I live (and also where Nestlé have their HQ, hehe) I never found any Nescafé Classic, only "Gold", "Red" and whatever... I used to buy it when on holidays in Greece, but I have seen it in stores in France too. Are you sure the Nescafé Classic sold in Greece is different than in other countries? BTW: When you're in Greece,  try out a caffé freddo! It's a real Espresso with ice topped with foamed milk, I began to like it a lot more than frappé :)

Answer (score 1):

Use less water or more dried coffee.

Answer (score 1):

My error was that I poured the water along the edge of the glass, I had to pour it directly on the foam, in this way the water dissolves the coffee since it has a bigger surface in contact with the foam.